# Can i add an index to a table in Tilda for performance?

Tags: postgresql

We created a simple table in Tilda and want to create an index. How to do that?

```
 { "name": "Test"
  ,"description": "The table to keep track tests amd owners"
  ,"columns":[
     { "name": "id"        , "type": "STRING"                                       , "nullable": false, "size": 128, "invariant": true, "description": "The name of the test" }
    ,{ "name": "name"      , "type": "STRING"                                       , "nullable": false, "size": 128, "invariant": true, "description": "The name of the test" }
    ,{ "name": "test_fk"   , "sameAs":"Test.refnum"                                 , "nullable": false,              "invariant": true, "description": "The name of the test" }
     ]
   ,"primary": { "autogen": true }
   ,"foreign": [
        { "name":"Test", "srcColumns":["test_fk"], "destObject":"Test" }
     ]
}
```

Comment: What is this Tilda thing? What programming language is that? Typically you would run a `create index` command to create an index in Postgres

Comment: Hello, so sorry... this was a test message. Tilda is an open source project: https://github.com/CapsicoHealth/Tilda. Docs are in https://github.com/CapsicoHealth/Tilda/wiki and details about indices are https://github.com/CapsicoHealth/Tilda/wiki/Tilda-JSON-Syntax%3A-Object-Indices.

Comment: More people are starting to use it and i was trying to start some thread on stack overflow for it for better reach.

Answer (score 0):

You can see documentation details about Index creation in table definitions in the Wiki:

https://github.com/CapsicoHealth/Tilda/wiki/Tilda-JSON-Syntax%3A-Object-Indices

```json
    // Within an Object definition, you can define any number of indices (or none).
 "indices":[
      // A unique index that exists in the database over colA and colB
      { "name":"Blah1", "columns":["colA", "ColB"],                     "db":true }
      // A regular (non-unique) index that overlaps with the previous definition
      // but only exists for application needs (no database definition).
     ,{ "name":"Blah2", "columns":["colA"]        , "orderBy":["colB"], "db":false}
      // A regular index with only an orderBy definition.
     ,{ "name":"Blah3",                             "orderBy":["colB"], "db":true }
  ]
```

The markup above shows the JSON to create a variety of indices with comments explaining what each attribute does.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30724125)

Comment: Thanks Grant. I had a snippet of the JSON and i thought it was obvious. I just added an additional comment.